# How can I git filter-branch with a regular expression to remove files/directories from the history permanently?

Tags: git, version-control, git-filter-branch

Is there a way to pass `git filter-branch` a regular expression to remove files/directories permanently from the history?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to do an index filter (which won't need to change your work tree), you can script on all commits and only change the files you need by sed, egrep or grep on the output of `git ls-files`.

```
git ls-files --cached | \
sed 's/weirdprefix\(pattern\)/git reset HEAD weirdprefix\1/g' | \ 
xargs -i{} sh -c '{}'
```

(this is the script you would provide in the filter-branch command)

Here is an example from the documentation ( http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html ):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
        'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&newsubdir/-" |
                GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
                        git update-index --index-info &&
         mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

Comment: Whoops my fault, I forgot to mention that a want to DELETE files/directories from the history. Will edit my question.

Comment: Isn't `reset HEAD` a no-op for an index filter? Don't you have to use `rm --cached`?

Comment: Shouldn't is be `sed -n '.../gp'`? Without that it will print the unmodified lines, which will be mostly invalid commands, but if some file happens to be executable...

Comment: yes.. you are both correct.. I'm doing this out of my head without a test :( I'll update the answer later when I have time.. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with the command line, how do I provide this to the filter-branch command? And what is "weirdprefix"?

Comment: weirdprefix is just a dummy pattern you want to look for.